# Can I trigger a series of keyboard shortcuts with a single action on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, automation, shortcuts-app

For example, on an iPad with iOS 13, if I want to automate the following (in the app Notes):

Command Shift Down

Command X

Command Up

Down

Command V

Is there any way to trigger that sequence of keyboard shortcuts in a single way, such as a Shortcut or some other way?

Comment: Let’s get your first question answered. Feel free to ask a related / follow on question now or later as you see fit, but we generally close posts that are a sequence of questions

Comment: It may help to not only focus on the key sequence but also at the task you want to accomplish with them (as there may be different ways to get there). So what exactly do these commands give you?

Comment: @nohillside The idea is just to quickly cut some text and paste it to the top of a note.

Comment: You already have a question asking something like that, which currently is on hold and requires more detail. Asking a second, slightly different, question is usually not the best approach, can‘t you fix the first question instead (or edit the question above to provide a full picture)?